# Cypress is reporting the wrong size on element

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

I'm using cypress to test our pattern library elements. The alert pattern the `<p>` set to `font-size: 14px`. When I inspect the CSS and the dev inspector, I see the correct size being rendered.

But cypress is reporting `16.8px`. To double check, I asked cypress to log how high the `.alert` element is. The `cy.log` reports a height of 34px which is correct. The inspector reports a height of 60px. What is going on here?

[image]

```

```
/// <reference types="Cypress" />

context('AlertButtonClose', () => {
    it('Button close displays as designed', () => {
        cy.visit('?p=molecules-alerts')

        cy.get('#sg-viewport').then(function ($iframe) {
            const $jbody = $iframe.contents().find('body')

            // Alert Type - All
            const $alertAll = $jbody.find('.alert')
            cy.screenshot()

            cy.log('.alert height: ' + $alertAll.height())
            cy.wrap($alertAll)
                .should('exist', 'be.visible')
                .should('have.css', 'min-height').and('gte', '3.125rem')
            cy.wrap($alertAll).find('p')
                .should('exist', 'be.visible')
                .should('have.css', 'font-size', '14px')
            cy.viewport(639, 720)
            cy.wrap($alertAll).find('.alert-link')
                .should('not.be.visible')
            cy.viewport(960, 720)
            cy.wrap($alertAll).find('.alert-link')
                .should('exist', 'be.visible')
                .should('have.css', 'font-weight', '300', 'text-transform', 'uppercase', 'font-size').should('gte', '10.5px')

            if ($alertAll) {
                expect($alertAll)
                    .to.have.css('color', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)')
            }

            // Alert Type - Info
            const $alertInfo = $jbody.find('.alert-info')

            if ($alertInfo) {
                expect($alertInfo)
                    .to.have.css('background-color', 'rgb(3, 155, 229)')
            }

            // Alerts Type - Dismissable
            const $alertDismissable = $jbody.find('.alert-dismissable')

            if ($alertDismissable) {
                cy.wrap($jbody).find('.close').should('exist', 'be.visible')
                cy.wrap($jbody).find('.close img')
                    .should('have.css', 'height', '15px')
                    .should('have.css', 'width', '15px')
                    .should('have.attr', 'alt').should('not.be.empty')
                cy.wrap($jbody).find('.close img')
                    .should('have.attr', 'src').should('include', 'close-alert.svg')

                cy.wrap($jbody).find('.close').click()
                cy.wrap($jbody).find('.alert-dismissable').should('not.exist')
            }
        })
    })
})
```

```

Additionally, the image generated by `cy.screenshot() is crazy over-sized! The alert bar appears to be over 80px in height which utter nonsense.

[image]

Comment: Might this be a bug with Cypress? This seems very strange indeed.

Comment: It's seeming to behave like one. I'll log the issue in the git repo and see if it checks out. I just wanted to do due diligence and see if anyone else had encountered this or not.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a bug per se. We are taking an approach to responsive design where we're changing the base-font size on the `body` tag. It seems as if Cypress is unable to recalculate based on breakpoint in the manner we've implemented:

```
html {
    font-size: $font-size-base; //16px

    @media (min-width: 640px) {
        font-size: $font-size-base-md; //18px
    }

    @media (min-width: 960px) {
        font-size: $font-size-base-lg; //20px
    }
}

li, p {
    @include font-size(14)
}
```

For such a small pattern, the test has morphed into a rather complex exercise:
///

```
describe('Alert Close Button', () => {

    context('iphone-5 resolution', () => {
        beforeEach(function () {
            cy.viewport('iphone-5')
        })

        it('GLOBAL & XS breakpoint: Alert displays as designed', () => {
            cy.visit('?p=molecules-alerts')

            cy.get('#sg-viewport').then(function ($iframe) {
                const $jbody = $iframe.contents().find('body')

                // Alert Type - All
                const $alertAll = $jbody.find('.alert')

                cy.log("alert height: " + $alertAll.height())
                cy.wrap($alertAll)
                    .should('exist', 'be.visible')
                    .should('have.css', 'min-height').should('be.gte', '50px')
                cy.wrap($alertAll).find('p')
                    .should('exist', 'be.visible')
                    .should('have.css', 'font-size', '14px', 'font-weight', '800', 'line-height', 'calc(14 / 18)', 'min-height', '2.6rem', )
                cy.wrap($alertAll).find('.alert-link')
                    .should('not.be.visible')

                if ($alertAll) {
                    expect($alertAll)
                        .to.have.css('color', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)')
                        .to.have.css('padding', '.4375rem 3.125vw')
                }

                // Alert Type - Info
                const $alertInfo = $jbody.find('.alert-info')

                if ($alertInfo) {
                    expect($alertInfo)
                        .to.have.css('background-color', 'rgb(3, 155, 229)')
                }

                // Alerts Type - Dismissable
                const $alertDismissable = $jbody.find('.alert-dismissable')

                if ($alertDismissable) {
                    cy.wrap($jbody).find('.close').should('exist', 'be.visible')
                    cy.wrap($jbody).find('.close img')
                        .should('have.css', 'height', '15px')
                        .should('have.css', 'width', '15px')
                        .should('have.attr', 'alt').should('not.be.empty')
                    cy.wrap($jbody).find('.close img')
                        .should('have.attr', 'src').should('include', 'close-alert.svg')

                    cy.wrap($jbody).find('.close').click()
                    cy.wrap($jbody).find('.alert-dismissable').should('not.exist')
                }
            })
        })
    })

    context('ipad-2', () => {
        beforeEach(function () {
            cy.viewport('ipad-2')
        })

        it('SM breakpoint: Alert displays correctly', () => {
            cy.visit('?p=molecules-alerts')

            cy.get('#sg-viewport').then(function ($iframe) {
                const $jbody = $iframe.contents().find('body')

                // Alert Type - All
                const $alertAll = $jbody.find('.alert')

                if ($alertAll) {
                    expect($alertAll)
                        .to.have.css('color', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)')
                        .to.have.css('padding', '.75rem 3.125vw')
                }
            })
        })
    })

    context('tablet-mixed', () => {
        beforeEach(function () {
            cy.viewport(960, 600)
        })

        it('MD breakpoint: Alert displays correctly', () => {
            cy.visit('?p=molecules-alerts')

            cy.get('#sg-viewport').then(function ($iframe) {
                const $jbody = $iframe.contents().find('body')

                // Alert Type - All
                const $alertAll = $jbody.find('.alert')

                cy.wrap($alertAll)
                    .should('exist', 'be.visible')
                    .should('have.css', 'min-height').and('gte', '2.625rem')
                cy.wrap($alertAll).find('p')
                    .should('exist', 'be.visible')
                    .should('have.css', 'font-size', '16px')
                cy.wrap($alertAll).find('.alert-link')
                .should('exist', 'be.visible')
                .should('have.css', 'font-weight', '300', 'text-transform', 'uppercase', 'font-size', '10.5px')
            })
        })
    })
})
```